# Change the default language for Oracle Express

Tags: oracle, express

I have installed **Oracle Database 11g Express Edition**, the default language of the of which after my installation is not English

[image]

Is it possible to use the SQL command line tool or something rather to modify the language setting of it, so it would be English again? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the NLS_LANG environment variable, SQL*Plus should pick that up, e.g:

```
SET NLS_LANG=English
```

Comment: Found it, [set the environment variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html), thanks a lot